# Forward local port to remote port in a Vagrant machine

Tags: iptables, vagrant

I have MySQL running on my local machine and I need to publish this port to a Vagrant box without any special SSH hackery.

Is there a way for me to forward 10.0.2.2:3306 to 127.0.0.1:3306 on the Vagrant box using iptables? If so, how can I debug it to make sure I get things right?

Comment: The other question is asking about on the same host, I'm asking for forwarding to a different host.

Comment: Are you wanting to access the MySQL instance on your "local machine"(i.e. a development machine) from the Vagrant Box _as if_ it was the "localhost" ie. 120.0.0.1 on the Vagrant box?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.